# How to accept space in regex?

Tags: regex, expression

I have this regex:

```
const name_regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
```

I tested this with the following regex tool

[link](http://www.regextester.com/)

Can you please tell me how to do to accept and space?

Accept eg: `John Smith`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes,anywhere in the input

Answer (score 18):

Just add a space  or `\s` (to allow any space character like tab, carriage return, newline, vertical tab, and form feed) in the character class

```
^[a-zA-Z ]+$
```

Note: This will allow any number of spaces anywhere in the string.

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cZ1vQ3/3)

If you want to allow only a single space between first name and last name.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

1. `^`: Start of the line anchor
2. `[a-zA-Z]+`: Match one or more letters
3. `(?:`: Non-capturing group
4. `\s[a-zA-Z]+`: Match one or more letters after a single space
5. `?`: allow previous group zero or one time
6. `$`: End of line anchor

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cZ1vQ3/2)

```css
input:valid {
  color: green;
}
input:invalid {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input pattern="[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)?" />
```

To allow multiple names/string separated by a space, use `*` quantifier on the group.

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z]+)*$
                         ^
```

[**RegEx Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/cZ1vQ3/4)

Comment: Note that `\s` matches every whitespace character including tabs, newlines etc.